# Duplicate by changing the array combination in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, combinations

I have a product variation combination ID.  Hyphen (**-**) The characters between the strings represent the variation options id.

I want to make copies of other IDs for free variation options based on the main combination ID.

**My codes:**

```
function find_replace($array, $find, $replace){
    $array = array_replace($array,
        array_fill_keys(
            array_keys($array, $find),
            $replace
        )
    );
    return $array;
}

function get_var_key($array, $value){
    $key_name=false;

    foreach ($array as $n=>$c)
    if (in_array($value, $c)) {
        $key_name=$n;
        break;
    }

    return $key_name;
}

$get_free_keys = array(
    "var1" => array(
        "free1", 
        "free2"
    ),
    "var2" => array(
        "free3", 
        "free4"
        )
);
$main_combine = "a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free3";

$main_combine_explode = explode("-", $main_combine);

for($i=0; $i < count($main_combine_explode); $i++){
    $get_key_by_value = get_var_key($get_free_keys, 
    $main_combine_explode[$i]); // return "var1" or "var2"

    foreach($get_free_keys[$get_key_by_value] as $values){
        $find_combine = find_replace($main_combine_explode, 
        $main_combine_explode[$i], $values);
        $combines[] = implode("-", $find_combine);
    }
}


print_r($combines);
```

**Wrong result:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free3 // main combine (ok)
    [1] => a1-b1-free2-c1-d1-free3 // ok
    [2] => a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free3 // wrong
    [3] => a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free4 // wrong
)
```

**Result is incorrect**

I want to get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free3-e1 // $main_combine
    [1] => a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free4-e1
    [2] => a1-b1-free2-c1-d1-free3-e1
    [3] => a1-b1-free2-c1-d1-free4-e1
)
```

or

```
Array
(
    [var1] => Array
        (
            [0] => a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free3 // $main_combine
            [1] => a1-b1-free2-c1-d1-free3
        )
    [var2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a1-b1-free1-c1-d1-free4
            [1] => a1-b1-free2-c1-d1-free4
        )
)
```

Thank you.

Comment: This is not a code writing or research service. So show what you tried, please.

Comment: You post what you tried and I'll post solution - deal? (hint: this may come handy - https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/4688876)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my own code. Thanks for your reply.  I added my codes. @04FS

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add my own code. Thanks for your reply.  I added my codes. @dWinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [get_combinations](https://gist.github.com/cecilemuller/4688876) and [str-replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and do:

```
$template = "a1-b1-@FIRST@-c1-d1-@SECOND@-e1";
foreach (get_combinations($get_free_keys) as $e) {
    $res[] = str_replace(['@FIRST@', '@SECOND@'], $e, $template);
}
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/gXRXC)

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for! Thank you.